# Observable dentro de un for

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, observable, rxjs

Estoy practicando ionic2, estoy haciendo servicios con observables, en una parte hice un for y dentro de ese for llamé otro servicio pero parece que detiene el for y queda contando el total del array. ¿será por el observable que lo detiene? les muestro como lo estoy haciendo:

menu.ts

```
getMenusAjax():Observable<any>{
  return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/menu/todos')
    .map(res => res.json());
}
```

contenido.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()

export class contenidoServices{
  constructor(public http: Http){}

  getContenidoImagenes(id):Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(`http://localhost:3000/imgcont/${id}`)
        .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

page2.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

import { Me } from '../../app/commons/me';
import { MenuServices } from '../../app/services/menu';
import { contenidoServices } from '../../app/services/contenidos';

@Component({
 selector: 'page-page2',
 templateUrl: 'page2.html'
})

export class Page2{

  selectedItem: any;

  constructor(
   public navCtrl: NavController,
   public navParams: NavParams,
   private menu: MenuServices,
   private contenido: contenidoServices
  ){
    var contenidoDate = navParams.get('item');

    for (var j = 0; j < contenidoDate.length; ++j) {
      console.log(j);
      let images = contenido.getContenidoImagenes(contenidoDate[j].id);

      images.subscribe(
        res => {
          console.log(j);
          if(res != 2) {
            console.log(res);
            console.log(contenidoDate[j]);
          }
        },
        err => {console.log(err);}
      );
    }
    this.selectedItem = navParams.get('item');
  }
}
```

Resultado en consola, los umeros 0 y 1 imprime antes de llamar el servicio y el 2 imprime cuando ya se ha llamado el servicio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Ya solucionaste el problema?

Answer (score 0):

Exactamente es por los observables, ellos son una promesa que te llegara esa información pero no inmediatamente, de esta manera no bloqueas la pagina con esperas.

Si deseas usar múltiples observables existes varias herramientas, en tu caso creo te funcionara un `merge`
https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Combining-Observables

Answer (score 0):

La implementación no es la adecuada ya que estás saturando el back con muchas solicitudes, yo te recomiendo que en una sola url guardes toda la información de las imágenes y así con un sólo observable obtengas todo, imagina que tienes más de 100. Toda tu sistema se volvería inestable, es por eso que ya te está dando problemas.

Comment: vale, gracias, pero aveces no puedo tener acceso al back y solo me envían los sericios.